# After image uploaded page not redirect to ajax call success using Jsp

Tags: ajax, jsp

i am create simple image uploading system with help of stack over flow thanks with jsp with ajax.
image uploaded successfully.but after upload the image i want get the alert message what i wrote inside the ajax success function but it didn't work.after uploaded the image i got [{"success":"success"}] only
what i tried so far i attached below.
**index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

   <form id="upload-form" class="upload-box" action="upl.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
  
    <input type="submit" id="upload-button" value="upload" />
</form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Dropify/0.2.2/js/dropify.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(function() {
        $('#upload-form').ajaxForm({
            success: function(msg) {
                alert("File has been uploaded successfully");
            },
            error: function(msg) {
                $("#upload-error").text("Couldn't upload file");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**upl.jsp**

```
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONArray"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.sql.*,java.util.zip.*" %> 
<% 

 JSONArray list = new JSONArray();   
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
String saveFile=""; 
String contentType = request.getContentType(); 
if((contentType != null)&&(contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)){ 
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream()); 
int formDataLength = request.getContentLength(); 
byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength]; 
int byteRead = 0; 
int totalBytesRead = 0; 
while(totalBytesRead < formDataLength){ 
byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead,formDataLength); 
totalBytesRead += byteRead; 
} 
String file = new String(dataBytes); 
saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10); 
saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n")); 
saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,saveFile.indexOf("\"")); 
int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("="); 
String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1,contentType.length()); 
int pos; 
pos = file.indexOf("filename=\""); 
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1; 
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1; 
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1; 
int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4; 
int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length; 
int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length; 
File ff = new File("F:/123/"+saveFile); 

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(ff); 
fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos)); 
fileOut.flush(); 
fileOut.close(); 

            obj.put("success", "success");
            list.add(obj);
            out.println(list.toJSONString());
            out.flush();

%>

<% 
Connection connection = null; 
PreparedStatement psmnt = null; 
try{ 
   
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
  connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ems","root","");
  psmnt = connection.prepareStatement("insert into employee(photo) values(?)"); 
  psmnt.setString(1, saveFile); 
int s = psmnt.executeUpdate(); 

         



} 
catch(Exception e){ 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
} 
} 
%>
```

what we have to do inside the upl.jsp page inorder to redirect to ajax success function.

Comment: does that alert shows up or not ?

Comment: not shows up please help me.

Comment: check your browser `network tab ->XHR` see if the request is successfull or not it should show `200` status

Comment: nothing shown up any thing blank shown up

Comment: i checked nothing shown up

Comment: does your page gets refresh  or redirect? when you click on submit button?

Comment: yes. and uploaded image success for the relavent folder. only alert message not working. when click submit button url shows http://localhost:8084/filejsp/upl.jsp like that on that page [{"success":"success"}] shown

Comment: other wise if you have a code for uploade the image with jsp ajax for easy give me thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225775/discussion-between-swati-and-hari-dran).

Comment: thanks alottttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt